# Bug report: similar questions scroll problem

Tags: bug

When I create a new question, enter a title, then scroll the "similar questions" window, the text scrolls while a copy of the text stays fixed. See the screen recording. This is on Firefox, Macos 10.14.

[image: Similar questions scrolling issue]